# JavaScript library for push/comet/reverse-ajax notifications?

Tags: javascript, comet, push, reverse-ajax

I'm planning on building a website where you can play (turn-based) games with other people. I need to be able to communicate which moves have been made. I think push-notifications are best suited for this. I've read a little bit about node.js; is that the way to go? Or are there other libraries that will make it easy to do this sort of thing?

Comment: socket.io and dnode will help you with node.js (I recommend dnode, it builds ontop of socket.io)

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of solutions with a number of different technologies. Node.js and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is just one popular solution.

If you are a Ruby developer then [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) (which also has a node.js version) or [juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) are options. For .NET there is [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) or [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/). For Java there's [jwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/jwebsocket/) or [WaterSpout Server](http://www.spoutserver.com/). There are many more too.

I'm maintaining a [list of realtime web technologies](https://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) which will hopefully be a good starting point.

Comment: why does the xsocket video have 'hey there delilah' as the bg song?? haha.. i'm interested in .net. looking into these now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what WebSockets is a good use case for. But you need a fallback for browsers without WebSocket support, so use [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), it has good support for Node.js.

Comment: That webpage is pretty sparse...what exactly is its relationship to node.js? As I understand it... node.js is both a server and a library?

Comment: @Mark: Yes, it's a communication library. You need the client library and a server part. It has support for multiple server languages, but I think it's most popular and has best support on the Node.js platform.

Answer (score 0):

I´m one of the developers on XSockets.NET, (as Phil says) there are many great solutions out there.
I recommend that you try a few and then decide what to use.

If you want to checkout XSocket.NET, just throw any questions at us and we´ll help. Contact info on the XSockets webpage

Regards
Uffe