# There a way to optimize the performance of svg?

Tags: javascript, charts, svg, d3.js

I'm making an application with d3.js, but I'm driving a lot of data and graphics are way too big, which is slowing me much navigation.

Could someone tell me what could be a solution or a way forward.

This is the application. http://www.ingeniosolido.com/s2m2/prototype30/line_zoom_actual_30_interval.html

This is the code.
https://gist.github.com/3854943

Comment: You don't provide us enough information. Please be more specific, and insert code here, not somewhere else.

Comment: Is the issue that dragging in the graph is slow in Firefox? Because it's not slow in other browsers AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove some (read: most/all) of the clip-paths? It's almost always faster to not use clip-path (unless it clips away expensive areas, e.g filters, opacity, complex geometry and so on).

It looked a bit like you could at least move some of the clipping up a level, to be on a parent <g> element for example.

Also, the svg you link to doesn't really qualify as big markupwise.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you are doing a lot of element specific interaction. You might consider rendering to canvas. See: [HTML5 canvas alternatives for d3.js, graph visualization library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591753/html5-canvas-alternatives-for-d3-js-graph-visualization-library)