# How do I get reference of old generated elements in HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Take a look at this example:

```
  var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

    // First rectangle created    
    ctx.fillRect(20,20,150,100);

    // Second rectangle created    
    ctx.fillRect(20,150,150,100);

    // Third rectangle created    
    ctx.fillRect(20,300,150,100);
```

I created three rectangles here. After creating third rectangle I want to rotate first rectangle. How do i get reference of first rectangle now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A canvas is just a dumb grid of pixels. It doesn't understand what shapes have been drawn on it. Your code (or a library that your code uses) must keep track of the shapes that you've drawn.

Instead, it sounds like you want a library to create a [scene graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph), like [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS), [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/), or [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/). These libraries will maintain a data structure that tracks what shapes have been drawn on the canvas, and they will then redraw them when you want to manipulate those shapes.

Answer (score 4):

You don't "get the reference" of a rectangle or something with canvas. All you have is a canvas with a context. On which you can draw. Period.

If you want to move the first rectangle, then clear it (using `clearRect`) and redraw the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Canvas itself is just pixels. It knows how to draw rectangles, but doesn't keep them layered.

To quote [Simon Sarris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5883032/352796):

> HTML5 Canvas is simply a drawing surface for a bit map. You set up a
>   draw (Say with a color and line thickness) , draw that thing, and then
>   the Canvas has no knowledge of that thing: It doesn't know where it is
>   or what it is, it's just pixels. If you want to draw rectangles and
>   have them move around or be selectable then you have to code all of
>   that from scratch, including the code to remember that you drew them.

The only exception is the [`isPointInPath`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-ispointinpath) method, but it has limitations.

**However**, there are some libraries that provide object-oriented interface for Canvas. Like [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) or [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com). They remember what you draw as objects (rectangles, circles and so on) and can layer them one over another, move around and add mouse/touch events. Much like DOM.

Comment: Note that Raphaël uses SVG and VML, not canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing functions like `fillRect()` does not return anything (returns void).

Meaning it simply renders the pixels, it does not create a rectangle object and return it. You'll need to store the rectangle coordinates yourself.