# How to stop sprite on collision (Keep it from walking on walls)?

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, html5-canvas, collision-detection

Thanks to ellertsmari, I am able to get collision detection.
[Adding Collision to Rectangles so Sprite Wont Go Through?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625639/adding-collision-to-rectangles-so-sprite-wont-go-through)

Just now I want to get my sprite to stop on collision so he won't be walking on walls.

Here's my link to the game:
https://yewtreedesign.github.io/441_HW/HW11/index.html

Here's the source code that helped me to use sprites.
https://dev.to/martyhimmel/moving-a-sprite-sheet-character-with-javascript-3adg

so I figure that :

`positionX + deltaX > 0`  (checks for left edge collision.)

`positionX + SCALED_WIDTH + deltaX < canvas.width` (checks for right edge collision.)

`positionY + deltaY > 0` (checks for top edge collision.)

`positionY + SCALED_HEIGHT + deltaY < canvas.height` (checks for bottom edge collision.)

I've tried using the guide of how collision is detected on the sprite.
I have accomplished getting the collision detection on the rectangles.

I've tried to add `walls.x`, `walls.y`, `walls.width`, and `walls.height` within the code where it prevents the sprite from going out of boundaries. My sprite still gets stuck on his starting point. I am not sure what I need to do. I am very new at this. I know instead of `canvas.height/canvas.width`. I should use `walls.height/walls.width`for the walls.

```
const SCALE = 1;
const WIDTH = 18;
const HEIGHT = 31;
const SCALED_WIDTH = SCALE * WIDTH;
const SCALED_HEIGHT = SCALE * HEIGHT;
const CYCLE_LOOP = [0, 1, 0, 2];
const FACING_DOWN = 0;
const FACING_UP = 1;
const FACING_LEFT = 2;
const FACING_RIGHT = 3;
const FRAME_LIMIT = 12;
const MOVEMENT_SPEED = 1;
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let keyPresses = {};
let currentDirection = FACING_DOWN;
let currentLoopIndex = 0;
let frameCount = 0;
let positionX = 0;
let positionY = 0;
let img = new Image();
let shiba = new Image();
let rays = new Image();
let doritos = new Image();
let walls=     [{"id": "wall1", "x": 105.3, "y": -1,    "width": 14.1, "height": 73.5},
                {"id": "wall2", "x": 366.5, "y": -1,    "width": 14.1, "height": 73.5},
                {"id": "wall3", "x": 367,   "y": 173.2, "width": 120,  "height": 14.1},
                {"id": "wall4", "x": -1,    "y": 173.2, "width": 120,  "height": 14.1},
                {"id": "wall5", "x": 105.3, "y": 267.5, "width": 14.1, "height": 73.5},
                {"id": "wall6", "x": 366.5, "y": 267.5, "width": 14.1, "height": 73.5}
              ];
              function drawWalls(){
                for(var i=0; i< walls.length; i++){
                  ctx.fillStyle="white";
                  ctx.fillRect(walls[i].x, walls[i].y, walls[i].width,walls[i].height);
                }
            }
            function collidingWith(walls){
              console.log("you are colliding with:", walls.id);

}
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownListener);
function keyDownListener(event) {
    keyPresses[event.key] = true;
}
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyUpListener);
function keyUpListener(event) {
    keyPresses[event.key] = false;
}
function loadImage() {
    img.src = 'atlus/mainsprite.png';
  shiba.src = 'image/shiba.gif';
  rays.src='image/shades.png';
  doritos.src='image/dorit.png';
  img.onload = function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  };
}
function drawFrame(frameX, frameY, canvasX, canvasY) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.drawImage(shiba, 225,20);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.drawImage(rays, 400,20);
  ctx.drawImage(doritos, 420,250);
  ctx.drawImage(img,
                frameX * WIDTH, frameY * HEIGHT, WIDTH, HEIGHT,
                canvasX, canvasY, SCALED_WIDTH, SCALED_HEIGHT);
  ctx.closePath();
}

loadImage();
function gameLoop() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawWalls();

  let hasMoved = false;
  if (keyPresses.ArrowUp) {
    moveCharacter(0, -MOVEMENT_SPEED, FACING_UP);
    hasMoved = true;
  } else if (keyPresses.ArrowDown) {
    moveCharacter(0, MOVEMENT_SPEED, FACING_DOWN);
    hasMoved = true;
  }
  if (keyPresses.ArrowLeft) {
    moveCharacter(-MOVEMENT_SPEED, 0, FACING_LEFT);
    hasMoved = true;
  } else if (keyPresses.ArrowRight) {
    moveCharacter(MOVEMENT_SPEED, 0, FACING_RIGHT);
    hasMoved = true;
  }
  if (hasMoved) {
    frameCount++;
    if (frameCount >= FRAME_LIMIT) {
      frameCount = 0;
      currentLoopIndex++;
      if (currentLoopIndex >= CYCLE_LOOP.length) {
        currentLoopIndex = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  if (!hasMoved) {
    currentLoopIndex = 0;
  }
  drawFrame(CYCLE_LOOP[currentLoopIndex], currentDirection, positionX, positionY);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
function moveCharacter(deltaX, deltaY, direction) {
  walls.forEach(walls=>{
  if( positionX + deltaX + SCALED_WIDTH > walls.x && positionX + deltaX < walls.x + walls.width
    && positionY + deltaY + SCALED_HEIGHT > walls.y && positionY + deltaY < walls.y +walls.height
  ){
    collidingWith(walls);
  }
})

if (positionX + deltaX > 0 && positionX + SCALED_WIDTH + deltaX < canvas.width) {positionX += deltaX;}
if (positionY + deltaY > 0 && positionY + SCALED_HEIGHT + deltaY < canvas.height) {positionY += deltaY;}
  currentDirection = direction;
}
```

Everything is showing up as it should. In the console, once you collided with one of the walls, it will show you have collided with wall[i].
Which is great. 
I just need help so my sprite won't be walking on walls.

UPDATE:

The sprite does stop when colliding with the wall... Problem is that teleports back to it's begining position...
https://jsfiddle.net/YewtreeStudio/b1v9Loey/4/

Comment: Throwing the towel for tonight, not sure what to do. I may go at this differently tomorrow :/.

Comment: The simplest way would be to just return from moveCharacter, if you have detected a collision, before you get to the position change stuff.

Comment: oooh, I haven't considered that. I'll try it.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you show me how it would look like? I am not sure where to start. If I am able to figure it out I'll let you know.

Comment: So far there is some progress... my Sprite gets catapolted once he gets in contact with walls. He ain't walking over the walls... so that's a start... Calling it another day.