# What are the benefits of using canvas instead of SVG?

Tags: svg, canvas

Both [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) and [pomax's Bezier library](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/) library use canvas for rendering on their pages. I would expect that for such eminently vector-y things, SVG would be the natural choice.

I assume they've thought that through, so what are the benefits of canvas for these use cases?

Comment: I won't designate this as answer, because I just googled it, but canvas is basically a bitmap that you can draw on, while svq is a scalable vector graphic, designed to be scalable after the fact. You just define objects that are then rendered. If you change the scale, the objects can be rerendered. On a canvas, if you rescale, the drawn pixels would be scaled, I suppose, but the objects would not be rerendered.

Comment: Probably raw performance, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882716/html5-canvas-vs-svg-vs-div.