# Ordering the svg elements visually

Tags: javascript, css, svg, charts

I have trouble with ordering SVG elements. I wrote a script that takes the ratio of each number in an array to the sum of the numbers in it and creates a pie chart with regard to these numbers. Now, I'm trying to add some animations, but inherently, when I try to scale up the size of a slice, it seems behind the following paths.

I've tried the add z-index but apparently, that property doesn't work on SVG elements. I've tried to use 3D transform but I learned that too doesn't work on SVG. How can I overcome this problem?

My code:

```js
var radius = 100
        var slices = [3,4,3]
        var sumSlices = slices.reduce((last,num) => last + num)
        var degrees = Array.from(slices, num => (360*num)/sumSlices)
        var colorPalet = ["#e668a0", "#53e1a0", "#53a7e1", "#f8a1c8", "#95f2c7", "#94caf0"]
        var pie
        var obj = new Array
        var t, f1, f2, g1, g2
        t = 0
        degrees.forEach((degree, i) => {

            obj[i] = new Object
            
            f1 = radius * Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*t)
            g1 = -(radius * Math.sin((Math.PI/180) * t))
            
            obj[i]["lGo"] = f1 + " " + g1
            t = degree + t
            f2 = (radius * Math.cos((Math.PI/180) * t)) - f1
            g2 = -(g1 + (radius * Math.sin((Math.PI/180) * t)))
            if(degree < 180) obj[i]["aGo"] = radius + " " + radius + " 0 0 0" + f2 + " " + g2
            else obj[i]["aGo"] = radius + " " + radius + " 0 1 0" + f2 + " " + g2
            
        })

        var tags = new Array
        obj.forEach((sl, i) => {
            
            tags[i] = '<path d="M'+ radius + " " + radius +' l'+ sl["lGo"] +' a'+ sl["aGo"] +' Z" fill="'+ colorPalet[i] +'" />'
        })

        document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = tags.reduce((a, b) => a + " " + b)
```

```css
        body {margin:0}

        .con {
            position: absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:50%
        }

        .conIn {
            position: absolute;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        svg {
            overflow: initial;
        }

        path {
            transition: 1s;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
            transform-origin: center
        }

        path:hover {
            transform:scale(1.4);
            
        }
```

```html
    <div class="con">
        <div class="conIn">
            <svg id="dd" width="100" height="100" >
               
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you noticed, SVG does not support `z-index`. This functionality was [proposed](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/z-index) and eventually rejected. An `<svg>` tag uses a single rendering/stacking context, and draws later children on top of earlier children.

Here are a few workarounds:

1. Use JavaScript to dynamically re-order items. You can add a `mouseenter` event handler that moves the element to the end of the stack:

   ```js
   document.getElementById("dd").childNodes.forEach((path) =>
     path.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) =>
       path.parentNode.appendChild(path)
     )
   );
   ```
2. Change your transition animations so that they don't cause overlap.  The natural way to do this would be to manually set the `.style.transitionOrigin` of your elements so that they scale from the center of the bar chart.  See [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).  This will require a bit of computation, but given that you're already computing all the coordinates, it shouldn't be too hard.
3. Create separate `<svg>` objects. Then you could use `z-index`, I believe. But positioning them relative to each other would be quite difficult, I think.

By the way, your code would be easier to work with in these ways if you didn't assemble an HTML string and set `innerHTML`, but instead uses `document.createElement` to create elements and then `document.getElementById("dd").appendChild` to add those elements as children.

Comment: This code seems like solving my problem, thank you. I have an additional question for you. Are HTML5 Canvas and SVG the things be chosen instead of each other or do they have different usage areas?

Comment: In your setting, SVG makes the most sense: you have fundamentally vector graphics, and want to smoothly scale and use transition effects.  Canvas is good for rendering raster objects and high performance, including things like video games (though SVG could make good video games too). See, for example, [HTML5 Canvas vs. SVG vs. div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882716/html5-canvas-vs-svg-vs-div).