# Try to have d3 stacked chart with canvas

Tags: d3.js

I would like to know if someone has an example of d3 stacked chart with canvas because the only example I found on internet are with SVG.

Thanks for your help, i dont know why it so hard to find example with d3 canvas

Try to have a stacked chart with canvas on d3 lib

Answer (score 0):

Your secondary question

> i dont know why it so hard to find example with d3 canvas

has an easy answer; namely, [SVG offers a lot of advantages over Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882716/html5-canvas-vs-svg-vs-div/5883032#5883032). Canvas is really only the preferred choice for raster images or when there are many thousands of objects to manipulate; this is rarely the case for a bar chart.

Having said that, it's not particularly hard to draw a bar chart using the standard HTML Canvas Context and, of course, you can use D3 to help.  Here's one approach:

```js
d3.csv(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sandialabs/slycat-data/master/cars.csv",
  d3.autoType
).then(function(cars) {

  // Massage the data into a form suitable for a stack.
  let data = [];
  d3.group(
    d3.sort(
      cars,
      (o) => o.Year,
      (o) => o.Cylinders
    ),
    (o) => o.Year,
    (o) => o.Cylinders
  ).forEach(function (cylinder_group, Year) {
    let accumulation = 0;
    cylinder_group.forEach(function (a, Cylinders) {
      data.push({
        Year,
        Cylinders,
        height: a.length,
        accumulation
      });
      accumulation = accumulation + a.length;
    });
  });
  
  // Define a few parameters
  let w = 800;
  let h = 500;
  let pad = 20;
  
  // Setup the scales
  let x_scale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map((o) => o.Year))
    .range([pad, w - pad])
    .padding(0.2);
  let max_count = d3.max(
    Array.from(d3.group(data, (o) => o.Year).values())
      .map((a) => a.slice(-1)[0])
      .map((o) => o.height + o.accumulation)
  );
  let y_scale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max_count])
    .range([h - pad, pad]);
  let color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain([3, 4, 5, 6, 8])
    .range(d3.schemeCategory10);
  
  // Set up the canvas
  let canvas = d3
    .select('#viz')
    .append("canvas")
    .style("margin", `${pad}px`)
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .style("border", "solid 1px black");
  let ctx = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

  // Draw the rectangles
  data.forEach(function (o) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color(o.Cylinders);
    ctx.fillRect(
      x_scale(o.Year),
      y_scale(o.accumulation),
      x_scale(71) - x_scale(70) - 15,
      y_scale(o.height) - y_scale(0) + 3
    );
  });

  // Draw the axes
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pad, y_scale(0));
  ctx.lineTo(w - pad, y_scale(0));
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  d3.range(70, 83).forEach(function (x) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_scale(x) + 26, y_scale(0));
    ctx.lineTo(x_scale(x) + 26, y_scale(0) + 8);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillText(x, x_scale(x) + 20, y_scale(0) + 15);
  });
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  d3.range(0, 45, 5).forEach(function (y) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pad, y_scale(y));
    ctx.lineTo(pad + 5, y_scale(y));
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fillText(y, pad - 15, y_scale(y) + 3);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<div id='viz'></div>
```

The data is the classic [cars dataset](https://github.com/sandialabs/slycat-data/blob/master/cars.csv). The bar chart illustrates number of cars per year from 1970 to 1982 with the bars stacked by number of cylinders. Thus, I guess we can see how the number of cylinders generally decreased over that time frame, with 4 cylinders becoming predominant - at least, for this sample.

Note that, if you were to draw the bar chart with SVG, then much of the code would be unchanged. You might be interested in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/c462a1b68e8dd2d1) that illustrates both approaches.