# Write custom text on mug from user by keyboard by Javascript, Html5

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to write text on mug.And change property like font-style, color, size by Javascript, Html5. Right now i am using Javascript, Html5.
[image]

I want to write text on this mug image and also want to change font color, font-size, font style and rotate text. 
I seen this link but i am not satisfied.
[How can I write text on a HTML5 canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697615/how-can-i-write-text-on-a-html5-canvas-element)
I can't give you original code. I have a sample code for this page.

HTML CODE:

```
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </body>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
$(function () {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var productImg = new Image();
productImg.onload = function () {
    var iw = productImg.width;
    var ih = productImg.height;
    console.log("height");

    canvas.width = iw;
    canvas.height = ih;

    ctx.drawImage(productImg, 0, 0, productImg.width, productImg.height,
                  0, 0, iw, ih);

    //start();

    // outline
    ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(88, 235.734375);
     ctx.bezierCurveTo(88, 234.734375, 204, 298, 327, 234.734375);
     ctx.stroke();
};
productImg.src = "https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0018872_inspirational_teacher_mug.jpeg";

var img = new Image();
img.onload = start;
img.src = "http://blog.foreigners.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Make-new-friends.jpg";
var pointer = 0;


function start() {

    var iw = img.width;
    var ih = img.height;

    var xOffset = 125,
        yOffset = 122;

    var a = 122.0;
    var b = 30.0;

    var scaleFactor = iw / (2*a);

    // draw vertical slices
    for (var X = 0; X < iw; X+=1) {
      var y = b/a * Math.sqrt(a*a - (X-a)*(X-a)); // ellipsis equation
      ctx.drawImage(img, X * scaleFactor, 0, 6, ih, X + xOffset, y + yOffset, 1, ih - 605 + y/2);
    }
}
```

});

I am only using Javascript, Html5. I have seen this link http://varunpes.net46.net/Fancy_Product_Designer_V3.0.7/example/cust-txt.jsp
But this plugin have use in Php. I don't want this functionality in Php.
Anybody have any idea please share with me. If Any body have different idea than also share with me.

Comment: Please include some code. Is the mug a <img> or in a <canvas>? Why isn't the text within a canvas sufficient, it meets all the requirements you mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write custom text in canvas with fabric js library.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$('#font').change(function(){
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if(obj){
    obj.setFontFamily($(this).val());
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});

function addText() {
  var oText = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', { 
    left: 100, 
    top: 100 ,
  });

  canvas.add(oText);
  canvas.setActiveObject(oText);
  $('#fill, #font').trigger('change');
  oText.bringToFront();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12">

<button class="btn" onclick="addText()">Add Custom Text</button>

<select class="browser-default"  id="font">
  <option>arial</option>
  <option>tahoma</option>
  <option>times new roman</option>
</select>
<br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="750" height="550" style="border:1px solid #333"></canvas>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```