# .append value of input text to <canvas> isnt displaying the output of .append('<p>' + value + '</p>')

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gemcodedigitalmarketing/zn5yLwh3/

What I want is the text in the customText input to be appended to the canvas. Though I am unsure as to why this is not working.

It works when I tried yesterday to append td and tr to a table. But maybe because its a canvas it needs a different way of adding text?

not sure... either way i would apprecaite help.

```
$('#addText').click(function() {
    var value = $('#customText').val();
    $('canvas').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
});
```

This is my jquery at the bottom of the page

```
<div class="assets">
<h3>Assets</h3>
<div class="text">
    <h4>Text</h4>
    <input id="customText" type="text">
    <button id="addText" class="btn btn-default">Add Text</button>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <h4>Images</h4>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <!-- List of images here -->
        <!-- <li><img src="images/sample.jpeg" class="img-rounded" /></li> -->
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- canvas -->
<div class="canvas col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="block">
        <!-- Add images and texts to here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the relevant html.

Hope that gives you guys enough to go on...

Comment: The content of a canvas are pixels, so YES, there is a different way of adding text to a canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697615/how-can-i-write-text-on-a-html5-canvas-element

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match your question. Do you have a `<canvas>` element or just a div with `class="canvas"`?

Comment: i just have a div class with the class canvas. Though it looks like I need to add a canvas from what everyones saying.

Comment: You don't need a canvas for text. Period. A canvas is for "pixel art", so images you want to manipulate programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `canvas` is not an *element* but a *class*.

This is from your fiddle:

```
<!-- canvas -->
<div class="canvas col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="block">
        <!-- Add images and texts to here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

So you have to use it in the selector as:

```
$('.canvas')
```

Don't forget the dot.

Comment: what did you get this from?

Comment: @devnull69 He probably looked at the fiddle, where it's clear there is no canvas element...?

Comment: from his fiddle. I copied the relevant part here.

Comment: @devnull69 Yep, very confusing naming.

Comment: whoops, sorry guys. let me update the fiddle with the relevant stuff