# Add header and footer text and download the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I'm creating a barcode generator. The Barcodes are generated successfully. But I need custom text to be inserted above and below the image. 
The following is my code. I want to add custom text to it. After adding text to above and below the image, I want to get the same text and barcode in a image when I click download button.
Thanks in Advance.

Here is the demo link
http://saigroups.in/barcode/

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head><title>Barcode Generator</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Barcode Generator Created BY Hariram" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/bwipp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/bwipjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/xhr-fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/bitmap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/symdesc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/canvas-toblob.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/lib/filesaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastSymbol  = localStorage.getItem('bwipjsLastSymbol');
    var lastBarText = localStorage.getItem('bwipjsLastBarText');
    var lastAltText = localStorage.getItem('bwipjsLastAltText');
    var lastOptions = localStorage.getItem('bwipjsLastOptions');
    var lastRotate  = localStorage.getItem('bwipjsLastRotation');
    var lastScaleX  = +localStorage.getItem('bwipjsLastScaleX');
    var lastScaleY  = +localStorage.getItem('bwipjsLastScaleY');
    var lastFntMono = +localStorage.getItem('bwipjsLastFontMono');

    var $sel = $('#symbol')
        .change(function(ev) {
            var desc = symdesc[$(this).val()];
            if (desc) {
                $('#symtext').val(desc.text);
                $('#symopts').val(desc.opts);
            } else {
                $('#symtext').val('');
                $('#symopts').val('');
            }
            $('#symaltx').val('');
            $('.saveas').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#proof-img').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#stats').text('');
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            canvas.width = canvas.width;
        });

    if (lastSymbol) {
        $sel.val(lastSymbol);
    } else {
        $sel.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    }
    $sel.trigger('change');

    if (lastBarText) {
        $('#symtext').val(lastBarText);
        $('#symaltx').val(lastAltText);
        $('#symopts').val(lastOptions);
    }
    if (lastScaleX && lastScaleY) {
        $('#scaleX').val(lastScaleX);
        $('#scaleY').val(lastScaleY);
    }
    if (lastRotate) {
        document.getElementById('rot' + lastRotate).checked = true;
    }
    if (lastFntMono) {
        document.getElementById('fontMono').checked = true;
    }

    $('#scaleX').spinner({ min:1 })
        .on("spinstop", function(ev) {
            $('#scaleY').val(this.value);
        });
    $('#scaleY').spinner({ min:1 });
    $('#render').button().click(render);
    $('.saveas').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    if (location.search.indexOf('proofs=1') != -1) { 
        // Show the images from BWIPP with Ghostscript
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.id                  = 'proof-img';
        img.style.visibility    = 'hidden';
        img.style.position      = 'absolute';
        img.style.top           = '0px';
        img.style.left          = '0px';
        $('#proof').append(img);
    }

    // Allow Enter to render
    $('#params').keypress(function(ev) {
        if (ev.which == 13) {
            render();
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('versions').textContent =
                'bwip-js ' + BWIPJS.VERSION + ' / BWIPP ' + BWIPP.VERSION;
});

function render() {
    var elt  = symdesc[$('#symbol').val()];
    var text = $('#symtext').val().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
    var altx = $('#symaltx').val().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
    var opts = $('#symopts').val().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
    var rot  = "N";

    // Anti-aliased or monochrome fonts and scaling factors.
    var monochrome = document.getElementById('fontMono').checked;
    var scaleX =  2;
    var scaleY =  2;

    localStorage.setItem('bwipjsLastSymbol',  elt.sym);
    localStorage.setItem('bwipjsLastBarText', text);
    localStorage.setItem('bwipjsLastAltText', altx);
    localStorage.setItem('bwipjsLastOptions', opts);
    localStorage.setItem('bwipjsLastScaleX', scaleX);
    localStorage.setItem('bwipjsLastScaleY', scaleY);
    localStorage.setItem('bwipjsLastFontMono', monochrome ? 1 : 0);
    localStorage.setItem('bwipjsLastRotation', rot);

    var bw = new BWIPJS(bwipjs_fonts, monochrome);

    // Clear the page
    $('#output').text('');
    $('#stats').text('');
    $('#proof-img').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $('.saveas').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.height = 1;
    canvas.width  = 1;
    canvas.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // Convert the options to a dictionary object, so we can pass alttext with
    // spaces.
    var tmp = opts.split(' '); 
    opts = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        if (!tmp[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        var eq = tmp[i].indexOf('=');
        if (eq == -1) {
            opts[tmp[i]] = true;
        } else {
            opts[tmp[i].substr(0, eq)] = tmp[i].substr(eq+1);
        }
    }

    // Add the alternate text
    if (altx) {
        opts.alttext = altx;
        opts.includetext = true;
    }
    // We use mm rather than inches for height - except pharmacode2 height
    // which is expected to be in mm
    if (+opts.height && elt.sym != 'pharmacode2') {
        opts.height = opts.height / 25.4 || 0.5;
    }
    // Likewise, width.
    if (+opts.width) {
        opts.width = opts.width / 25.4 || 0;
    }
    // BWIPP does not extend the background color into the
    // human readable text.  Fix that in the bitmap interface.
    if (opts.backgroundcolor) {
        bw.bitmap(new Bitmap(canvas, rot, opts.backgroundcolor));
        delete opts.backgroundcolor;
    } else {
        bw.bitmap(new Bitmap(canvas, rot));
    }

    // Set the scaling factors
    bw.scale(scaleX, scaleY);

    // Add optional padding to the image
    bw.bitmap().pad(+opts.paddingwidth*scaleX || 0,
                    +opts.paddingheight*scaleY || 0);

    var ts0 = Date.now();
    try {
        // Call into the BWIPP cross-compiled code.
        BWIPP()(bw, elt.sym, text, opts);

        // Allow the font manager to demand-load any required fonts
        // before calling render().
        var ts1 = Date.now();
        bwipjs_fonts.loadfonts(function(e) {
            if (e) {
                $('#output').text(e.stack || (''+e));
            } else {
                show();
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        // Watch for BWIPP generated raiseerror's.
        var msg = ''+e;
        if (msg.indexOf("bwipp.") >= 0) {
            $('#output').text(msg);
        } else if (e.stack) {
            $('#output').text(e.stack);
        } else {
            $('#output').text(e);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Draw the barcode to the canvas
    function show() {
        bw.render();
        var ts2 = Date.now();

        canvas.style.visibility = 'visible';
        setURL();
        $('#stats').text('Rendered in ' + (ts2-ts0) + ' msecs');
        $('.saveas').css('visibility', 'visible');
        saveCanvas.basename = elt.sym + '-' +
                text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9._]+/g, '-');

        // Show proofs?
        if (location.search.indexOf('proofs=1') != -1) { 
            var img = document.getElementById('proof-img');
            if (img) {
                img.src = 'proofs/' + elt.sym + '.png';
                img.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
    }
}

function saveCanvas(type, ext) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                      saveAs(blob, saveCanvas.basename + ext);
                  }, type, 1);
}
function setURL() {
    var elt  = symdesc[$('#symbol').val()];
    var text = $('#symtext').val().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
    var altx = $('#symaltx').val().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
    var opts = $('#symopts').val().replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
    var rot  = document.querySelector('input[name="rot"]:checked').value;
    var mono = document.getElementById('fontMono').checked;
    var scaleX = +document.getElementById('scaleX').value || 2;
    var scaleY = +document.getElementById('scaleY').value || scaleX;

    var url = 'http://bwipjs-api.metafloor.com/?bcid=' + elt.sym + 
                '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(text) +
                (altx ? '&alttext=' + encodeURIComponent(altx) : '') +
                (opts ? '&' + opts.replace(/ +/g, '&') : '') +
                (rot != 'N' ? '&rotate=' + rot : '') +
                (scaleX == scaleY ? '&scale=' + scaleX
                                  : '&scaleX=' + scaleX + '&scaleY=' + scaleY) +
                (mono ? '&monochrome' : '');

    document.getElementById('apiurl').href = url;
}
</script>
</head><body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Barcode Generator</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<div id="params">

    <table class="table table-hover table-condensed" width="100%">
    <tr><td>code Type:</td>

        <td><select id="symbol"  class="form-control"  >

            <option value="code128">Barcode </option>
            <option value="qrcode">QR Code</option>
            </select></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bar Text:</td><td><input id="symtext" class="form-control" type="text" style=""><input id="symaltx" type="hidden" style=""><input id="symopts" value="showborder" type="hidden" style=""></td>
    </tr>


        <tr><td colspan="2"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="render">Show Barcode</button>   <a class="saveas" href="javascript:saveCanvas('image/png','.png')">Save As PNG</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="saveas" href="javascript:saveCanvas('image/jpeg','.jpg')">Save As JPEG</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="saveas"  style="visibility:hidden" id="apiurl" href=""></a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>
    <div id="content">
<canvas id="canvas" width=1 height=1 style="border:1px solid #fff;visibility:hidden"></canvas>
<div id="proof" style="position:relative;border:1px solid #fff"></div>
<div id="output" style="white-space:pre"></div>
</div>

    <table id="tobehid" class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="visibility:hidden">
    <tr><td>Scale X,Y:
        <input type="hidden" id="scaleX" value=2>
        <input type="hidden" id="scaleY" value=2></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Image Rotation:
        <label for="rotN"><input type="radio" name="rot" value="N"
            id="rotN" checked>Normal</label>
        <label for="rotR"><input type="radio" name="rot" value="R"
            id="rotR">Right</label>
        <label for="rotL"><input type="radio" name="rot" value="L"
            id="rotL">Left</label>
        <label for="rotI"><input type="radio" name="rot" value="I"
            id="rotI">Invert</label></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Font Rendering:
        <label for="fontAnti"><input type="radio" name="font" value="A"
            id="fontAnti" checked>Anti-Aliased</label>
        <label for="fontMono"><input type="radio" name="font" value="M"
            id="fontMono">Monochrome</label></td></tr>

    </table>

</div>


</body>

<div class="footer">Copyright by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/iamharistr">Hariram</a> <strong></strong></div>
</html>
<style>
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  color : #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}</style>
```

Comment: the barcode image does not have any text in it, the save code is just saving whatever the image has, so you could add text to the barcode image, and it will be saved when you click save

Comment: @am05mhz How to do it? I downloaded the above code from GITHUB. I dont know how to do it.

Comment: err, just write a text to the canvas, google n stackoverflow is your friend, a quick search give me https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_text and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697615/how-can-i-write-text-on-a-html5-canvas-element

Comment: @am05mhz I'm new here. Can you please show how to do  it in fiddle?