# Draw canvas text outside the rectangle along the edges

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to write the description of each edge along the rectangle. The reason is to describe the length of each edge inside and outside rectangles (alongside). Is there a way I can achieve it?

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// Clip a rectangular area
ctx.rect(50, 20, 200, 120);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.clip();
// Draw red rectangle after clip()
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
```

This should show 200 above the top edge (outside) and 150 along the left edge (outside)

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10337796/3294944) to see how to write text on the canvas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using @stealththeninja's comment (pointing to this answer - [text in html canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697615/how-can-i-write-text-on-a-html5-canvas-element/10337796#10337796)) and this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9t56r0y/3/) (for text rotation), I was able to build the code below. Hope it fits within your specs.

Screenshot of the result attached.
[image: html canvas text rotated]

```js
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    const rectPosX = 50;
    const rectPosY = 50;
    const rectLength = 200;
    const rectHeight = 150;

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(rectPosX, rectPosY, rectLength, rectHeight);

    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillText('200', rectPosX + rectLength / 2, rectPosY);
    ctx.fillText('150', rectPosX, rectPosY + rectHeight / 2);
    ctx.fillText('200', rectPosX  + rectLength / 2, rectPosY + rectHeight);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(rectPosX + rectLength, rectPosY + rectHeight / 2);
    ctx.rotate(0.5*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillText('150', 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```